# Event sourcing - How to recover missed events

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Lets say that I have two aggregates deployed in two separate services. Aggregate 2 listens to the events of aggregate 1.

When I stop aggregate service 2 for a long time, how do I recovery all the missed events?

1. Retrieve all missed events from aggregate 1 event store?
2. What if aggregate 1 already accumulated a lot of events. Is aggregate 2 allowed to use aggregate 1's snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Retrieve all missed events from aggregate 1 event store?

Yes.

> 2) What if aggregate 1 already accumulated a lot of events. Is aggregate 2 allowed to use aggregate 1's snapshot?

Yes.

However, in an heavily disconnected context that priviledges **partition tolerance** over **consistency**, you have to arrange compensating actions for all events handled by the aggregate 2. Indeed you can encounter situations where events that have been handled by aggregate 2 would have not been possible if it had recieved properly the events from the aggregate 1.

Comment: I'm surprised that aggregate 2 can use the snapshot because that would mean that aggregate 2 service must know how to deserialize aggregate 1

Comment: If I understood your question, aggregate2's system is already coupled with events from aggregate1. In comparison to this, deserialization's concerns are relatively small since it should be easy to build a Aggregate1SnapshotProvider for those that need it. Note however that this is not a theoretical suggestion, just a pratical one that is useful if the events' application degradates performances too much. But remember: measure performance **before** than trying to fix them!

Answer (score 1):

> Retrieve all missed events from aggregate 1 event store?

Yes, this would be the general approach. At an infrastructure level, you can remember the last seen sequence number, and then request that events since then are pushed to you.

> What if aggregate 1 already accumulated a lot of events. Is aggregate 2 allowed to use aggregate 1's snapshot?

The answer here is probably not - if the two are able to share a snapshot, it may be worth reconsidering whether or not the aggregate boundaries are correct in the first place. However, it really depends on the nature of the feed from aggregate 1. I'd generally avoid this unless you actually run in to problems where it becomes necessary.